# Induction on exponent rule for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction

Prove: $(a^k)^m = a^{km}$ for all $k, m$ integers.

Attempt: I am looking at the case where $m < 0$ and $k >0$. I am doing induction on a positive integer $m$, but $-m$ will become a negative integer.

Let $P(k,m)$ be the statement $(a^k)^{-m} = a^{k(-m)}$.

Base Case: $P(2,1)$, $(a^2)^{-1} = a^{2(-1)}$ , simplifying this will become the identity $e$ on both sides.

Now suppose as inductive hypothesis that $P(k,m)$ holds. We need to show that 
$(a^k)^{-(m+1)} = a^{k(-(m+1))}$.

So, working from the left $(a^k)^{-(m+1)} = a^{-km -k} = a^{-km} \times a^{-k} = a$.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a^k)^{-(m+1)}=(a^k)^{-m-1}=(a^k)^{-m}(a^k)^{-1}=(a^{k(-m)})(a^{k(-1)})=a^{-mk}a^{-k}=a^{-mk-k}=a^{k(-m-1)}=a^{k(-(m+1))}$